# My manager seems to be judging my performance by only a single skill

Tags: manager, tech-industry, technology

I've been working for an international company during last year. It's a software company that has its own product. I really like this company and recently I've received a raise.

I've spent countless hours working after hours and sometimes during the weekend to show how I'm engaged with company purpose. Besides, I'll always make sure to present the best solution that I can.

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be enough for my manager. During last month he has been complaining a lot about my behaviour when addressing comments in Pull Requests. He said that I'm not taking my time to evaluate each comment and I'm  just rushing through comments trying to close my Pull Request as soon as possible. I've tried to slow down a little bit, but it doesn't seem to be enough. Should I be worried? Am I gonna be fired? How can I manage this situation? My manager does not seem to be a flexible person.

Comment: Why not slow down more if slowing down a little isn't enough? (I'm assuming "but it seems to be enough" should actually be "but it *doesn't* seem to be enough" or you wouldn't have a problem.)

Comment: “Am I gonna be fired?” seems like a big leap here. Most likely he just wants you to take the time to think about (and hopefully benefit from) others’ feedback. I guess you were rushing through originally because you were stressed, and now you are stressing about this. Try to chill a little.

Comment: They're not judging all of your performance by a single skill. They're giving you feedback on a single skill (or lack). Talk to them. All for techniques on correction. Get timelines and metrics. Ask the questions: "what are your expectations of me for this?" And "what metrics can I use that will tell me I've accomplished this goal?"

Answer (score 13):

> I've spent countless hours working after hours and sometimes during the weekend **to show how I'm engaged with company purpose**.

What looks like engagement to you looks like inefficiency to your managers. You are supposed to finish your work in 40 h/week, instead of 60(?) h/week.

> During last month he has been complaining a lot about my behaviour when addressing comments in Pull Requests. **He said that I'm not taking my time** to evaluate each comment and I'm just rushing through comments trying to close my Pull Request as soon as possible.

Then it is possible that you do not a thorough job when analyzing whatever you have to analyze. **Doing things fast** and **doing things good** are not the same thing. If your company expects quality before speed, then do not reverse the priorities just because you want to show off.

> Should I be worried?

If you actually improve, then no need to worry. At least, not much.

> Am I gonna be fired?

Only if you do not show improvement.

> How can I manage this situation?

Your manager already did the work for you. You just need to comply. You are actually very lucky. Most of the managers will only tell you about what you did wrong during yearly evaluation, as a pretext to not give you a raise. You manager talks to you when needed, AND you got a raise. It is unreasonable to expect much more.

One thing you can do additionally, is to initiate discussions with your manager, when you are not sure that you understood something correctly. Just be careful not to overdo it. Too many questions will raise another flag in your manager's mind.

> My manager does not seem to be a flexible person.

Well, according to your description, your manager is actually a good manager. It seems that it is you who are not flexible: *"I've tried to slow down a little bit, but it seems to be enough."* (probably *"doesn't seem to be enough"*)

As long as your manager guides you, let yourself guided. I wish I had such managers in my life. I did not, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the [prior answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/164424/19325), but will answer a specific point: "I'll always make sure to present the best solution that I can".

The best solution you can find as an individual may not be the best solution that would be possible with input from your colleagues. The problem may be how you are thinking about pull request comments. They are not just a formality to be disposed of. You need to examine each pull request comment in the hope that it will lead to an improvement in your solution.

Comment: ha ha :) I had an idea of saying the same thing with different words: "*your* best might not be *the* best" or "*your* best might be not good enough". +1

Answer (score 0):

More likely that your manager just talks about the only thing that he or she thinks needs improving. He looks at ten things, nine are fine, one needs improving. So don’t worry. And if that’s the case, a manager wouldn’t fire someone who gets nine out of ten, when there is no guarantee that any replacement will be even half as good as you are.

BTW. Doing a 60 hour week guarantees that you are not doing your best. Most people achieve more in 40 hour weeks than in 60 hour weeks.